# int variable value not accessible in ActionEvent JButton body

Tags: java, swing, static, integer

My code snippet is below:

```
static int i=0;
JButton ar[]=new JButton[5];
for( i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     ar[i]=new JButton(" Button number : "+i);
     ar[i].addActionListener((ActionEvent clicked) -> {
     System.out.println(" Clickevent detected on JButton number "+i);
});
panel.add(ar[i]);
```

In output of program , it is printing *"Clickevent detected on JButton number 5"* in every instance, I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly prefer to use a copy of loop variable after before actionevent code in loop and print that and try to declare loop variable inside loop .
Like this :

```
       JButton ar[]=new JButton[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    ar[i]=new JButton(" Button number : "+i);
int ci=i;
ar[i].addActionListener((ActionEvent clicked) -> {
System.out.println(" Clickevent detected on JButton number "+ci);
});
panel.add(ar[i]);
}
```

It would work if you make these changes .

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek11 if the solution is working then accept the answer